# Create closure for an imported constructor javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

The situation is as follows:

I have two objects, `f1` and `f2`. These objects come from constructors which exist in modules `'./test.js'` and `'./test2.js'`, respectively.

I need methods of `f2` to be able to access properties of `f1`.

Instead of passing `f1` into the constructor of f2, I would rather have both objects
scoped so they can see each other. However, I would prefer if they weren't both floating around as globals.

The issue is that these constructors were defined in separate modules. So I tried to close the object constructors by "redefining them" within the shared scope:

```
import {f1Constructor} from './test.js'
import {f2Constructor} from './test2.js'

(function(){
    var closed_f1C = f1Constructor
    var closed_f2C = f2Constructor
    var f1 = new closed_f1C()
    var f2 = new closed_f2C()

    .
    .
    .

})()
```

So that in the methods of the f2 constructor we can have:

```
f2Constructor.prototype = {
    .
    .
    .
    method1: function(){
        var s = f1.x
        .
        .
        .
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is this type of behavior possible in javascript?

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Did you try running this? What happened. Also no need to redefine new variables as constructor.

Comment: @VLAZ To have both objects f1 and f2 share the same outer scope

Comment: @drakzuli that would be the Y. The X would be the *reason* for that.

Comment: All code inside your IEFE can refer to both `f1` and `f2`, any function you define for one object can "see" the other. But the methods defined in the constructors, or on their prototypes, cannot see anything other than the `this` value - they don't even know about the particular instance `f1` or `f2`, any number of objects might be instantiated. So no, you definitely **should** pass the objects to the other constructor.

Comment: @drakzuli Please show us the code of *test.js* and *test2.js* where you would want to access `f1` and `f2`

Comment: @Bergi just to add to "*you definitely should pass the objects to the other constructor*" - since this is tagged OOP, then that's how good OOP design is *supposed* to work. If an object requires another object, you pass them in. Rather than sharing globals.

Comment: @Bergi just posted pseudocode for test2

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah my OOP tag is a bit misleading... I know javascript is not technically an OOP language so I'm open to other ways of solving the problem

Comment: @drakzuli you can still apply OOP principles to JS. Point is that the "shared global instances" is bad design in *any* language if you're focusing on OOP.

Comment: @drakzuli Why does test2 create the `f1Constructor.prototype`? Please post actual code, not pseudecode. What are you doing with that `s` variable, why do you need to access `f1` in a method of any `f2constructor` instance?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry that was a typo, just fixed it. test2.js creates prototype for f2 constructor

Comment: The biggest question is *why* can you not pass an instance of `f1` to `f2`, why should the instance be shared?

Comment: @Bergi ```s``` is an object that handles undo/redo operations in my application, and both objects make changes to the application. Now that i'm writing this, i'm wondering if I should just seperate ```s``` entirely from ```f1```. However, even if I do this the problem still stands if ```s``` is not global.

Comment: @VLAZ I can pass ```f1```into ```f2```, but wouldn't that keep ```f1``` in two different locations in memory? ```f1``` is a very big object.

Comment: @drakzuli no it wouldn't. See, that was your X. Could have been solved 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh ok, I see. Would it just be 1 copy of ```f1``` and 1 reference of ```f1``` as opposed to two copies?

Comment: @drakzuli one object in memory, with two references to it. If one reference went out of scope (e.g., it's initialised in a function) then that *variable* is gone. The object remains and there is still one reference remaining in `f2`.

Comment: @VLAZ gotcha. thanks for the help. I understand now what u meant by the XY problem. Sorry this took longer than needed.

Comment: @drakzuli JS is explicitly an OOPL. Not being class-based (syntactic sugar aside) is a separate thing.